# How can I extract text from a PDF file (without the header)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am tryin' to extract text from a PDF file using Python, and my main goal is to extract text in the main file without the header.

Here is the sample image, and the header refers to the red rectangle:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEkV6.jpg)

And here is the PDF file link: https://mega.nz/file/d0YkhB5Y#j7eA0EBxg70Yu36PjGocNjouP_xQFoRRAN7VfyDeClo

What is currently the best and easiest way to extract text from a PDF file into a string?
I have tried using pdfplumber, but after reading the user guide of it, I still have no clue how to use it.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What module do you use? Where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900539/how-to-stop-pdfplumber-from-reading-the-header-of-every-pages/66902615#66902615)

Answer (score 1):

The repo of **pdfplumber** is [here](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber). It is a great package to extract text, character, rectangle, and line in addition to table extraction. A simple example is:

```
import pdfplumber

def extract_pdf(pdf_path):
    all_text = ''
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            all_text = all_text + '\n' + single_page_text
    return all_text

pdf_path = 'test.pdf'
text = extract_pdf(pdf_path)
print(text)
```